# Applying logistic regression to data recorded on a 0-10 scale

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, biostatistics, epidemiology

I used 0-10 scale to record disease data on `each` plant.

0 = no disease
1 = 1–10% of plant leaves infected
2 = 11–20% of plant use infected
.
.
.
10 = 91–100% of plant leaves infected.

I am considering dividing the response variable by 10 to create a proportion and then using logistic regression. While I am aware that an ordered beta distribution can be used for rank data, I am interested in using the binomial family. Can I apply logistic regression in this context, and are there any considerations or adjustments I should be aware of for this type of data?

**Analysis goal**
Predict disease based on weather conditions

Comment: In this setup, what do you see as having a binomial distribution?

Comment: Do you have, for each plant, the total number of leaves and the number of infected leaves?

Comment: A binomial distribution gives integers. Where are your integers?

Comment: Sure, you get predictions on the interval $[0,1]$. What does a binomial distribution have to do with this?

Comment: As your response is ordinal, an ordinal regression model should be appropriate, e.g. a *cumulative link* model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(p) = \log\left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)$. Then it sounds like you want to model:

$$
g\left(\mathbb E[Y\vert X]\right) = X\beta
$$

and estimate $\beta$ as $$\hat\beta = \underset{\hat\beta_0}{\arg\max}\left\{
\sum_i\left[
y_i\log\left(\hat p_i\right) + \left(1 - y_i\right)\log\left(1 - \hat p_i\right)
\right]\bigg\vert \hat p_i = g^{-1}\left( \hat\beta_0^TX_i\right)
\right\}$$

This is logistic regression when the $y_i\in\left\{0,1\right\}$, and the estimation $\hat\beta$ is maximum likelihood estimation that gives nice properties for the coefficient point estimates, confidence intervals, and hypothesis tests.

You can shoehorn your problem in this kind of model, sure, and you might even get good performance. However, I would hesitate to call it a logistic regression when you lack a binomial-distributed outcome.

A term you might use to describe your approach is that you are using an [extremum estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremum_estimator), in this case, optimizing the usual binomial likelihood despite the fact that you definitely do not have a binomial-distributed outcome (you know this with certainty because you do not have integer outcomes).

I have my doubts that this is the best approach to your problem and that you need to shoehorn your data into the wrong kind of model when more appropriate models seem to be out there (e.g., explicitly model the ordinal variable, such as with a proportional odds ordinal model), but you won't *really* know unless you try it.

Comment: @Ahsk That page is long. What in particular do you want to do? If it isn't a logistic-style regression like you described in the OP, then how does the logistic-style regression come into play?

Comment: I tried it with simulated data and got the code to compile, so you *can* run that kind of command, sure. It's a stretch to call it a logistic regression, however, and I see absolutely nothing going on that is related to a binomial distribution. Nonetheless, if you can validate such a model as giving strong performance...

Comment: @Ahsk I do not follow what you intend to do. Perhaps post another question asking about the viability of your approach. You can give more detail in a question than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks very similar to the study by Lucas et al. on the effect of ozone on Sitka spruce damage:

> P. Lucas, D. Cottam, L. Sheppard, and B. Francis. Growth responses and delayed winter hardening in Sitka spruce following summer exposure to ozone. New Phytologist, 108(4):495–504, 1988. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-8137.1988.tb04192.x

They encoded the damage $Y$ as an ordinal variable like you did and used the following *cumulative link* model:
$$P\big(Y\leq j\mid X=(x_1,\ldots,x_p)\big) = f(\alpha_j + \beta_1 x_1 \ldots +\beta_p x_p) \quad\mbox{ for }\;j=1,\ldots,k-1 $$
where $f$ is a link function, for which a logit or probit function is a typical choice. A simple implementation of this model comes with R in the function `MASS::polr`. Here is an example with the date for "10 November" in table 1 of the article by Lucas et al:

```
# data from table 1 (Lucas et al., 1988) for 10 November
dat <- data.frame(
  temp = rep(rep(seq(-9, -18, by = -3), 4),
             c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4)),
  ozone = rep(c(170, 120, 70, 0), c(16, 14, 15, 16)),
  damage = factor(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
                    4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 0, 
                    1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 
                    2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)),
  count = c(1, 10, 2, 2, 8, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 4, 
            9, 1, 9, 4, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 
            6, 3, 2, 1, 6, 6, 2, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 5, 9, 2, 11, 
            2, 1, 6, 6, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3)
)

# fit model
library(MASS)
 fit <- polr(damage ~ temp + ozone, data=dat, weights=dat$count, method="logistic")

# plot predicted probabilities according to model
link.model <- fit$lp
sort.key <- order(link.model)
x <- link.model[sort.key]
plot(x, fit$fitted.values[,1], ylim=c(0,1), type="n",
     xlab="link value z", ylab="P(Y<i|z)")
p.model <- t(apply(fit$fitted.values, MAR=1, FUN=cumsum))
levs <- levels(dat$damage)
for (i in 1:(length(levs)-1)) {
  lines(x, p.model[sort.key,i], col=i, type="l")
}
legend("topright", c("none", "1-25%", "26-50%", ">50%, but not all"), lty=1, col=1:4)
```

[image: plot of model predictions]

The R package `ordinal` provides more elaborate implementations that can also compute prediction intervals.